# Access env variables in config file

Tags: java, maven, selenium, circleci

I have a custom Selenium project which uses Maven. I am getting the config properties from `test.properties` file and it is used across the code by using a ConfigManager class. Now I need to hide some config info from the version control and planning to add it as an environment variable. How can my `test.properties` file access these environment variables? the file now has hard coded values and I want to replace it with environment variables and from there it will be read and executed by the code.

So I need to know how can I access the env variables in local and in Circle CI.

Comment: Either read env variables directly, or have Circle auto generate your properties file.

Comment: So how can I read the env in this test.properties file ?

Comment: You can't. You need to read them from Java.

Answer (score 1):

```
package com.facebook.configs;
import lombok.Getter;

@Getter
public enum LocalConfig {
    INSTANCE;

    private String community = System.getenv("FACEBOOK_URL") ==null ? "www.facebook.com" : System.getenv("FACEBOOK_URL");
    private int port = System.getenv("PORT") == null ? -1 : Integer.parseInt(System.getenv("PORT"));
    private String protocol = System.getenv("PROTOCOL") == null ? "http" : System.getenv("PROTOCOL");
    private String username= System.getenv("USERNAME") == null ? "USER_EMAIL_OR_PHONE" : System.getenv("USERNAME");
    private String password= System.getenv("PASSWORD") == null ? "USER_PASSWORD" : System.getenv("PASSWORD");
}
```

You can do something like above, I have created a sample config file. You will have to set the environment variable value in IDE respectively or pass from jenkins it will be passed as a environment variable. Also, you can have a default value if the key value is null it will pick the default value, as shown.

> LocalConfig.INSTANCE.getProtocol() + "://" +
>   LocalConfig.INSTANCE.getCommunity()

You can directly access the variable like one shown above.